# Kendo Grid, multiGrids in tabStrip on POPUP Editor

Tags: kendo-ui

In kendo grid, I have popup editor for user.

in this popup, I have kendo tabstrip contains two kendo Grid in two tabs.

I want to do like this :
+ The first Grid in first tab load dataSource (read) by add parameter UserID of Model User in popup.

```
 .Read(read => read.Action("ReadUserBranch", "User", new { UserIDSys = @Model.IDSys }))
```

- And the second tab is grid "Store" read datasource by parameters list and UserID, How to add array list from First Grid .

  Read(read => read.Action("ReadUserStore", "User").Data("DataStore"))

Thanks ALL... help me !

Answer (score 0):

You can view link: http://www.telerik.com/forums/tabstrip-content-inside-edit-template

Download code: [KendoPopupEditorWithTabStrip.zip](http://www.telerik.com/clientsfiles/ce9f2864-9e5f-4a70-aa73-ab77a862eab2_KendoPopupEditorWithTabStrip.zip?sfvrsn=0)

Can you add nick skype of me ( kaka_nnc ) , We can learning Kendo UI together ...